# How to create a DataTrigger programatically with Binding="{Binding}"?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatrigger

What's the equivelant of this `DataTrigger` in C# code?

```
<DataTrigger
  Binding="{Binding}"
  Value="{x:Null}">
    <Setter
      Property=SomeProperty
      Value=SomeValue />
</DataTrigger>
```

I am skeptical on how to create the `Binding`. Is this correct?

```
var trigger = new DataTrigger();
trigger.Value = null;
// Is this sufficient?
trigger.Binding = new Binding();
// Code to create the setter
// ...
```

Comment: You should have searched first before posting your question. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/797753f4-5db2-4852-a9fb-1ed989fe6413/add-datatrigger-programmatically?forum=wpf

Comment: I've seen this link. It's the `Binding="{Binding}"` that I don't know how to create.

Comment: I specifically wrote it in the title @Andy

Comment: `trigger.Binding = new Binding(".");` should be equivalent. However, neither that nor `Binding="{Binding}"` makes sense on a DataTrigger, because it lacks a source property that could be updated and thus trigger the Trigger.

Comment: A binding (created in XAML) without a Path (or a Path with value '.') will still have a the DataContext as implict Source. And the DC can change from null to not null. So in XAML it would work - on DataContextChanged event.
In code behind, I think the Source must be actively, explictly set, otherwise the trigger has a no Source  or null as its Source and the condition will always be true.

Comment: Could be when the trigger is added to a FrameworkElement's style and thus becomes part of the visual tree, the current DataContext potentially could also automatically become the Source (of the triggers Binding).
Testing is above studying, as they say.

Comment: In that case, an ordinary Trigger on the DataContext property would be more obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the equivalent of your XAML:

```
var trigger = new DataTrigger()
{
    Value = null,
    Binding = new Binding(".")
};
trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter() { Property = SomeProperty, Value = SomeValue });
```